# continuous gps tracking for every x minutes in android even if app is closed (or force closed)

Tags: android, gps, android-service

I am designing an Android Application which posts the GPS coordinates if (GPS enabled and network Enabled ). For the time being i did not write code for Posting data.
I have written code, for background service , and calling service . through  some tutorials . Can Any one please Judge is this correct Way

```
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.Ringtone;
    import android.media.RingtoneManager;
    import android.media.ToneGenerator;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
    import android.os.Vibrator;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class AndroidLocationServices extends Service {

        WakeLock wakeLock;

        private LocationManager locationManager;

        public AndroidLocationServices() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate();

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(this.POWER_SERVICE);

            wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotSleep");

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.e("Google", "Service Created");

        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.e("Google", "Service Started");
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started",
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    15*1000,0, listener);
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }


    //  @Override
    //  @Deprecated
    //  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    //      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //      super.onStart(intent, startId);
    //
    //      Log.e("Google", "Service Started");
    //       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started",
    //               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //
    //      locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
    //              .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //
    //      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
    //              15*1000,0, listener);
    //
    //  }

        private LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.e("Google", "Location Changed");

                if (location == null){
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext



    (), "Location null",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;

                }else{
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location null else",
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
                try {
                    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                    r.play();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (Util.isGPSAvi() && Util.isNetAci()) {

                    // JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                    // JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                    try {
                        Log.e("latitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
                        Log.e("longitude", location.getLongitude() + "");

                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Latitude : " + location.getLatitude()
                                        + " :: Longitude : "
                                        + location.getLongitude(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // jsonObject.put("latitude", location.getLatitude());
                        // jsonObject.put("longitude", location.getLongitude());
                        //
                        // jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                        //
                        // Log.e("request", jsonArray.toString());

                        // new LocationWebService().execute(new String[] {
                        // Constants.TRACK_URL, jsonArray.toString() });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In Exp "+e.getMessage(),
                                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onProviderDisabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onProviderEnabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStatusChanged",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDestroy",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            wakeLock.release();

        }

    //  public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context _context) {
    //      ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
    //              .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    //      if (connectivity != null) {
    //          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
    //          if (info != null)
    //              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
    //                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
    //                      return true;
    //                  }
    //
    //      }
    //      return false;
    //  }



    }
```

And in Starting Screen App Login Button onClick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    startService(new Intent(this, AndroidLocationServices.class));

    And starting intent to go for another screen 


}
```

And Manifest File

```
 <service
        android:name="com.xxx.gps.AndroidLocationServices"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

Comment: try to create class which extends Application ... mention this class in Manifest file... then check

Comment: so AndroidLocationServices should extend Application ?

Comment: no create  new class extends Application instead of service/activity

Comment: In that what i should write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to keep service running in the background if user force-closes or kills the app.

To improve chances of the service for not being killed when system running low on memory I would recommend to make it [foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). You would also need to make it foreground to avoid being suspended in Android Marshmallow (see [Power-Saving Optimizations](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-power)).

You can also take a look at [Traccar Client open source GPS tracking app](https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-client-android). You can either take it as a base for your app or just borrow some ideas from there.

Comment: Will the Above code Work(code in question) , if Running in Background ? Or Should i make any changes. Is it good to call in me Login Screen startService(new Intent(this, AndroidLocationServices.class)); every time ? Please help

Comment: I think it should work. It doesn't matter from where you call `startService`. Android system will make sure that there is only one instance of the service.

Comment: Please Help to Accept Answer , Will the code work in following conditions ?
    1. Continously Track GPS Coodrinates if app running in foreground and background.
    2. If app is forced killed(it will not work as you mentioned), But it should restart(Continously Track GPS Coodrinates) when App opened and started.
    3. Is there any Changes I should make.
    Please Help.

Comment: 1. Yes, it should work as far as I can tell, but of course you need to try it.
2. You need to start service again.